# A new update from Google Chrome screwed up my navbar, why?

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I did update my chrome today, before updating its working was OK but after this, my navbar acting like this. After refreshing page, when I click on some link or toggle it then it looks OK. I don't know what's the matter.

[image: bootstrap navbar]

Comment: did you try forcing the cache to reload ? ctrl+F5

Comment: @painor yes i tried, but the same problem.